# In python3, after installing mysqlclient, dependancy for MySQLdb persists

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I have shifted to `python3` and trying to create my web application using `django 1.11.1`, i.e the latest version.

I have `virtualenv` set up where I have installed all my requirements.

As per [django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers), I have opted for the 2nd option i.e installed `mysqlclient`. Now, when I am trying to migrate my basic django tables, I am getting following error:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "/home/namita/environments/p3_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module> 'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'. Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

Did I miss any package ? Plus, when I tried installing mysql-python, it gives `ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'` which is fair as I am using python3. Also I checked the point of line where the error is coming, it has something like this

```
try:
    import MySQLdb as Database
except ImportError as e:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        'Error loading MySQLdb module: %s.\n'
        'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
    )
```

This means it is expecting MySQLdb packpage. Is it required in in python3 as well ? Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed `mysqlclient` correctly in the virtualenv? What do you get if you activate the virtual environment then run `pip freeze`, or try `import MySQLdb as Database` the the Python shell?

Comment: Resolved, I `mysqlclient` installed outside of virtualenv.